# Is it possible to make two different build configurations to use same auto-incrementing build number?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe5, buildconfiguration

Our new version is in pre-release phase and I'm setting up a new build configuration for it. The problem is that for next month we need to do our daily builds for same product with two different configs. These configs have different major-minor-release numbers, but I'm not sure what to do about the build number. I can reserve for example 200 numbers for old version, but I just prefer to keep same incremental logic for both versions that makes tracing changes more clear.

Comment: Set the build number explicitly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's always an option, but it's unsafe and really annoying.

Comment: No it's not. It's the only really robust way. You need to stop letting the IDE manage this and do it yourself.

Comment: Why is it unsafe? It's only annoying for the time it takes you to automate it, which I wouldn't expect to be very long.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is this a usual rule or you are just suggesting it for my situation? If it's a rule then what is the purpose of auto-increase option?

Comment: @RobKennedy I mean it increases risk of making mistakes if it's done non-automatically, but you're right about the automation. I'm just checking to see if msbuild has such capability.

Comment: The IDE's facilities for versioning are useless. Auto increment is rather hopeless when you have more than one developer. Or branch. Roll your own version and build management.

Comment: http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2015/09/26/using-my-buildtools/ especially the section on "Version Information, Icon and Manifest"